# Почему цвет у всех одинаковый?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(function (){
 $('div').css('background', $('div').html());
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>red</div>
<div>yellow</div>
<div>blue</div>
<div>green</div>
<div>black</div>
```

Почему у всех красный цвет а не разный?

Comment: а какой ты ожидаешь?

Comment: Я ожидал что цвет блока будет соотвествовать названю

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`each()` - не обязателен.

`.css()` - вторым параметром может принимать функцию, которая возвращает, что угодно. В данном случае можно вернуть свой же `html` (http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```js
$(function (){
    $('div').css('background', function(){ return $(this).html(); });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>red</div>
<div>yellow</div>
<div>blue</div>
<div>green</div>
<div>black</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому что он берет текст первого попавшегося элемента div :) и он красный, делай так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', $(this).html());
  })

});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>red</div>
<div>yellow</div>
<div>blue</div>
<div>green</div>
<div>black</div>
```

Здесь ты получаешь все элементы `div` и проходишь по ним по очереди функцией `each()`, `$(this)` это конкретно текущий элемент, и ему присваиваешь background равный содержимому текущего элемента `div`.